# How to use QVariant to convert an enum to a QString

Tags: c++, qt, enums, qstring

In order to convert an enum in C++ to a QString one can do the following:

```
    template<typename QEnum>
    static QString QtEnumToString (const QEnum value)
    {
        QString valueString = QVariant::fromValue(value).toString();
        return valueString;
    }
```

This will generate a QString for an enum declared as:

```
    enum class Type{Text, Html, Image, URL};
    Q_ENUM(Type)

    Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ClipboardItem::Type) // this goes outside the class
```

So for example the output of:

```
    qDebug() << ClipboardItem::QtEnumToString(Type::Html);
```

is "Html".
Now I would like to do the reverse operation but couldn't find a way. What I have tried is this:

```
    static QVariant::Type QStringToQtEnum (const char *name)
    {
        return QVariant::nameToType(name);
    }
```

However, if I try to run `QStringToQtEnum("Type::Html")` the output is always `QVariant::Invalid`.

Comment: `QMetaEnum::fromType<ClipboardItem::Type>().valueToKey("Html")`

Comment: Note that the compiler is *not strictly required* to embed the names of your enums into your executable. On some platforms, and for sure only in release more, your enum of type "enumType" with definitions for "a" and "b" could print as "enumType<1>" and "enumType<2>" instead of "enumType::a". Last tested and observered on UWP using MSVC2015.